# Setting Up Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am following the code posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) on setting up an alarm manager but I can't get it to work at all.

This code is in a class called "Alarm":

```
package com.sjjgames.abortionapp;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

I have added this code to the manifest:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.sjjgames.abortionapp.YourService" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

This is in a class called "YourService":

```
package com.sjjgames.abortionapp;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I expect a toast to display every 5 seconds.

Comment: Good question but I am just following the tutorial in the link display above.  The YourService class activates the alarm class.

Comment: At what point does your service gets triggered? I dont see any line where "YourService" starts.

Comment: Doesn't this line in the manifest trigger the "YourService" class? <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.sjjgames.abortionapp.YourService" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service doesn't call onStart() method. Instead of onStart() method you need to use onStartCommand():

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    alarm.setAlarm(this);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I suggest you to add @Override annotation to each overridden method in your classes. So if you add @Override to onStart() method the code will not be able to compile and error will be easier to spot.